# It's good to work and it's good that you work . What is the difference?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

It's good to work and it's good that you work . What is the difference ?
I feel that the first one is more general but the second one might mean that the person already works and we praise that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically, the first sentence simply means that working in general is a good thing, whereas the second sentence means that it is good that the person you are addressing is working.