# What does "good to talk" mean at the back of Nescafe instant coffee jars?

Tags: expressions

On the back of the jar, it says "good to talk" followed by telephone numbers and whatnot. I get that it's their "customer support" stuff, but why "good to talk"? Is that like an expression in English? Sounds almost British somehow. "Good to talk"...

Does it mean that they are "good to talk" as in "we are willing to talk", that it's "good to talk" in general, or something else? I couldn't find the expression on Wiktionary, which is where I always look up expressions first.

Comment: Are you asking what "good to talk" means or why it's being used in this context?

Comment: Related: [It's good to work & Its good that you work – what is the difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457101/its-good-to-work-and-its-good-that-you-work-what-is-the-difference). But the 'It's good to V' snowclone is not really covered per se. 'It is good to V' (V a suitable verb) is a variant of 'Ving is good [for you / us ...] to do'.

Comment: You could phone them and ask, if you're sitting down relaxing with a cup of coffee ;)

Answer (score 5):

"It's good to talk" was an advertising slogan used by British Telecom some decades ago to encourage people, particularly men, to chat on the telephone more. (This was before mobile phones/cellphones became universal.) So, yes, Nescafe want to encourage you to contact them if you have a query or problem.

Comment: The correct (specific) answer, but there are those who haven't the same memory. A link?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Bob Hoskins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jtyn1jJajjI). Remember him?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, and Maureen Lipman.

Answer (score 3):

It may refer to  BT’s ad campaign of the 90’s:

"[It's Good to Talk"](https://www.campaignlive.co.uk/article/its-good-talk-story-behind-campaign/938629) - the story behind the campaign

> LONDON - It's been almost two decades since BT's "It's Good To Talk" commercials hit the screen. Robert Bean, who worked for both WCRS and BT on the account, tells the story behind the successful campaign.